# Error when there's a constructor in Model class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a ASP.NET Core WEB API.

If I include a constructor in my User Model, I get an error. And I cant run any requests, like a GET Users request for example.

Any clue as to what Im doing wrong? Am I not allowed to have a constructor in my model? If not, what else can I do because I need a way to initialize a new user some how in my other functions.

The error:

```
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'User'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'u' in 'User(string u)'.
```

```
// USER MODEL
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
        public bool EmailNotifications { get; set; }

        public User(string u) // THE CONSTRUCTOR IN QUESTION
        {
            this.UserID = 0;
            this.Username = u;
            this.IsAdmin = false;
            this.EmailNotifications = false;

        }

    }
```

```
        // GET: api/Users
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
        {
            return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Add default constructor as well.

Comment: I encourage you to read the error message again. It actually is a good error message with a lot of detail.

Answer (score 2):

you need to supply a default constructoras EF is looking for a default paramaterless constructor in you case.

```
// USER MODEL
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool EmailNotifications { get; set; }

    public User() { // you are missing this one

    }

    public User(string u) // THE CONSTRUCTOR IN QUESTION
    {
        this.UserID = 0;
        this.Username = u;
        this.IsAdmin = false;
        this.EmailNotifications = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: ...or one that has the properties as it's parameters.